# LibGDX Scene2D: Applying Actions to Actors in separate class

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I'm having trouble getting a MoveToAction to work on an Actor (menuBackground), when the Actor is in a separate class. I have attached relevant code below- which doesn't make the Actor move at all.

I have had success in apply other actions to the root stage in the MainMenuScreen class, and to a different Actor (Button) in the MainMenuScreen class, but have had no success applying actions to Actors in a separate class.

I've tried putting the MoveToAction in the act(float delta) method within the MenuBackground class, but that didn't work either. Neither did assigning the MoveToAction to the menuBackground from within the MainMenuScreen class.

Note that I am making a call to super.act(delta); within my MenuBackground class.

I would ultimately like to put the code for the MoveToAction within the Actor MenuBackground class, to make things neat and tidy.

Cheers.

**Class containing stage:**

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen
{
     private Stage stage;
     public MainMenuScreen()
     {
         stage = new Stage(new FitViewport(800, 480));
         Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

         menuBackground = new MenuBackground();
         MoveToAction moveToAction = new MoveToAction();
         moveToAction.setPosition(242f, 276f);
         moveToAction.setDuration(10f);
         menuBackground.addAction(moveToAction);
         stage.addActor(menuBackground);

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) 
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);    
        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
...
}
```

**Actor Class:**

```
public class MenuBackground extends Actor
{
    private Texture menuBackgroundTexture;
    private float actorX;
    private float actorY;

    public MenuBackground()
    {
        menuBackgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/menuTitleTexture.png")); 
        actorX = 242f;
        actorY = 350f;
        setBounds(actorX,actorY,316,128);   
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha)
    {
        batch.draw(menuBackgroundTexture,actorX,actorY);
    }

    @Override    
    public void act(float delta)
    {
        super.act(delta);    
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Does the actor display before you try and move it?

Comment: Yes it does, thanks William. It just wont move a muscle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is inside your `draw()` method.

Look at code draws your texture, it uses `actorX` and `actorY` which are actually fields that don't change their values.

The proper way is:

```
batch.draw(menuBackgroundTexture, getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
```

So, you should use actor's own fields and getters and don't manage yours.

Comment: Thanks Metaphore! I'd seen your proper way to do it before, but didn't actually realise my way was causing an error. Much appreciated.